# Trouble Loading Method in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx, es6-class

React NOOB issue I'm having:

I have a JSX file that uses Axios to make an API call:

`fetch-api-data.jsx`:

```js
import * as axios from 'axios';

export class FetchApiData {
  constructor() {
    console.log('FetchAPIData loaded');
  }

  shareMyStoryData(URL) {
    return axios.get(URL)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

I have a component that references that API call:

`share-my-story.jsx`

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import * as DOM from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './share-my-story.scss';
import FetchApiData from './fetch-api-data';

class ShareMyStory extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const URL = '/js/feed/sms.json';
    const smsData = FetchApiData.shareMyStoryData(URL);
    console.log('shareMyStory.jsx - componentDidMount: load: ' + URL);
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div className="item">
            <h3>{headline}</h3>
            <h4>{name}</h4>
            <p>{link}</p>
          </div>

      );
  }
}

ShareMyStory.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  headline: PropTypes.string,
  link: PropTypes.string,
}

DOM.render(
    <ShareMyStory/>, document.getElementById('share-my-story'));
```

However, when webpack compiles the items and they are run in the browser, I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'shareMyStoryData' of undefined`

Is there some reason why the shareMyStoryData() method isn't available in the `share-my-story.jsx` file? Both of the files are in the same folder, and I can see that both the `fetch-api-data.jsx` and `share-my-story.jsx` file are getting properly bundled together in my `bundle.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 problems in your `fetch-api-data.jsx`:

1. You should you [`export default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export) instead of [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_named_exports).
2. You made the spelling mistake in [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) method.
3. You added `shareMyStoryData` [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) method but used it without creating a class instance. Maybe it should be [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods)?

Check out the fixed example:

```js
import * as axios from 'axios';

export default class FetchApiData {
  constructor() {
    console.log('FetchAPIData loaded');
  }

  static shareMyStoryData(URL) {
    return axios.get(URL)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Even accounting for the constructor typo, still get the same error with this change: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shareMyStoryData' of undefined`

Comment: @TWLATL I updated the answer, added `static` keyword to `shareMyStoryData`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! - not creating the class instance and not using static was the issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: @TWLATL I'm glad to help. You could also create a class instance, or create utils module without using `class` notation.

Answer (score 0):

You should export your class as default or import it with brackets.

```
const myFunc = () => {...};
export default myFunc;

import myFunc from 'myfunc.js';
```

---

```
const myFunc = () => {...};
export myFunc;

import  { myFunc } from 'myfunc.js';
```